# Getting values of properties in SoapUI's groovy

Tags: groovy, properties, soapui

I'm pretty new to testing and SoapUI and I've just faced a problem:
I have 2 soap requests from which I transfer data (using PropertyTransfer) to Properties - I can do that and it works fine for me.
But now I would like to take those values in my groovy script (which is next step of my testcase). How to do that? So far, I have found following:

```
testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("SomeProp")
```

But it doesn't work for me. I guess it's not that Properties. Any tips?

Comment: what does not work?  are there any errors, exceptions, ...?

Comment: In my "Properties step" I have a property named SomeProp with a value of "valOfProp". When I use log.info(testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("SomeProp")) I'm getting NULL.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the Groovy script panel you can right-click and select Get Data, to help you out. You will end up with something like this:

```
context.expand( '${Properties step#SomeProp}' )
```

Same thing can also be written as:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSteps['Properties step'].getPropertyValue("SomeProp")
```

Comment: The first expression doesn't work. The second one does. Another strange thing is that in my groovy script I can't rightclick->getData. It's just not there. I can do something similar in my soap requests. But not in groovy script. Can you advice with it? (I'm using newest free SoapUI version)

Comment: @user3447603 The right-click guide is a -Pro only feature, I think.

Comment: @siking : is it possible to get all the properties without providing property names?

Comment: @vineel There is a `public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, TestProperty> getProperties()`. https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/soapui/DefaultPackage/TestPropertyHolder.html

Answer (score 2):

Few cents:

if we are loading properties file through external file via -Dsoapui.properties=\tmp.properties

> Contents of tmp.properties
>
> serialNumber=908664374

ideal way to load the property 'serialNumber' in groovy file would be,

```
def serialnumber = context.expand('${#serialNumber}')
```

But if you have a property at any level [test suites, test cases or project] inside your SOAPUI project, say you have it at project level, then it would be

```
def serialnumber1 = context.expand('${#Project#serialNumber}')
```

Answer (score 1):

The first expression works with:

```
context.expand( '${Properties_step#SomeProp}' )
```

Answer (score 0):

To read property from Project level properties

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue( "PropertyName")
```

To read property from Test Case level properties

```
testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("PropertyName")
```

Answer (score 0):

Two answers are possible for this type of scenarios ,

*Setting and Getting the Property values,*

- Message Exchange
- Test Runner

**Message Exchange :**

```
def testCase=messageExchange.modelItem.testCase.getPropertyValue("Propertyname")
```

**Test Runner:**

```
testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("PropertyName")
```

**Note :** context also helps to retrieve the same .